# ParameterSubstitutionException: Passing bash variables to Pig parameters

Tags: bash, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am getting the error:

> 2014-07-30 14:34:07,104 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException: Undefined parameter : year found when trying to find the value of input.

after I do `./run_pig_script 2014-07-30`?

I am trying to pass in year, month, and day to the input parameter in Pig.

Here is a condensed version of my shell script, which is named `run_pig_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Hadoop Job Queue to use
JOB_QUEUE=LongRun

array=( "$@" )
time=${array[0]}

IFS='-' read -ra timestamp <<< "$time"
year=${timestamp[0]}
month=${timestamp[1]}
day=${timestamp[2]}

echo $year
echo $month
echo $day

pig -Dmapred.job.queue.name=$JOB_QUEUE -param "input=hdfs:///raw/tool/year=$year/month=$month/day=$day/hour=00/min=00/" -f process_data.pig
```

The error message appears in [org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.PreprocessorContext.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/branches/tez/src/org/apache/pig/tools/parameters/PreprocessorContext.java):

```
    while (bracketKeyMatcher.find()) {
        if ( (bracketKeyMatcher.start() == 0) || (line.charAt( bracketKeyMatcher.start() - 1)) != '\\' ) {
            key = bracketKeyMatcher.group(1);
            if (!(param_val.containsKey(key))) {
                String message;
                if (parentKey == null) {
                    message = "Undefined parameter : " + key;
                } else {
                    message = "Undefined parameter : " + key + " found when trying to find the value of " + parentKey + "."; 
                }
                throw new ParameterSubstitutionException(message);
            }
            val = param_val.get(key);
            if (val.contains("$")) {
                val = val.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\$", "\\\\\\$");
            }
            replaced_line = replaced_line.replaceFirst("\\$\\{"+key+"\\}", val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show how `bracketKeyMatcher` is initialized. Idem for `param_val`.

Comment: The error message appears in [org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.PreprocessorContext.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/branches/tez/src/org/apache/pig/tools/parameters/PreprocessorContext.java), which I did not write. The initialization for `bracketKeyMatcher` and `param_val` can be seen in that link.